# How can I append an element after select in d3?

Tags: d3.js

I have a simple data structure that I want to use to render svg with d3.

```
const data = [
  {
    project: "One",
    stages: [
      { name: "foo", items: [1, 2, 3] },
      { name: "bar", items: [2, 3] }
    ]
  },
  {
    project: "Two",
    stages: [
      { name: "bar", items: [2, 3] },
      { name: "baz", items: [3, 4] }
    ]
  }
];
```

I want to render this as a couple nested `<g>` elements -- one for the project and one for the stage.  Within each stage group, I want to have one `<rect>` representing all the `items` in the stage.  Finally, one more rect per item.  The final structure should look like:

```
<svg>
  <g class="project" data-project="One">
    <g class="stage" data-stage="foo">
      <rect class="range" />       <-- this doesn't get added -- why?
      <rect class="item" data-item="1" />
      <rect class="item" data-item="2" />
      <rect class="item" data-item="3" />
    </g>
    <g class="stage" data-stage="bar">
      <rect class="range" />       <-- this doesn't get added -- why?
      <rect class="item" data-item="2" />
      <rect class="item" data-item="3" />
    </g>
  </g>
  <g class="project" data-project="Two">
    <g class="stage" data-stage="bar">
      <rect class="range" />       <-- this doesn't get added -- why?
      <rect class="item" data-item="2" />
      <rect class="item" data-item="3" />
    </g>
    <g class="stage" data-stage="baz">
      <rect class="range" />       <-- this doesn't get added -- why?
      <rect class="item" data-item="3" />
      <rect class="item" data-item="4" />
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

I tried to model this like so:

```
// Project group elements
const projects = d3.select(svg.current).selectAll("g.project").data(data);
const projectsEnter = projects
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .classed("project", true)
  .attr("data-project", (d) => d.project);

// Stage groups within each project
const stages = projects
  .merge(projectsEnter)
  .selectAll("g.stage")
  .data((d) => d.stages);
const stagesEnter = stages
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .classed("stage", true)
  .attr("data-stage", (d) => d.name);

// "range" representing the whole stage
// !!!!!
// These rect.range elements don't get added
// !!!!!
const range = stages.merge(stagesEnter).select("rect.range");
const rangeEnter = range.enter().append("rect").classed("range", true);

// Items within each stage
const items = stages
  .merge(stagesEnter)
  .selectAll("rect.item")
  .data((d) => d.items);
const itemsEnter = items.enter().append("rect").classed("item", true);
itemsEnter.merge(items).attr("data-item", (d) => d);
```

This mostly works, *except* the `rect.range` elements don't get added. I seem to be incorrectly understanding what `select` does here:

```
const range = stages.merge(stagesEnter).select("rect.range");
const rangeEnter = range.enter().append("rect").classed("range", true);
```

What's the correct way to get a single `rect` added to each `g.stage` here?

Here's a codesandbox to demo my issue: https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-tdd-8tdoh?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1):

The code is simpler if you use [join](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/main/README.md#selection_join) rather than enter/append/merge:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="chart"></div>

    <script>
      const width = 500;
      const height = 500;

      const svg = d3.select('#chart')
        .append('svg')
          .attr('width', width)
          .attr('height', height);

      const data = [
        {
          project: "One",
          stages: [
            { name: "foo", items: [1, 2, 3] },
            { name: "bar", items: [2, 3] }
          ]
        },
        {
          project: "Two",
          stages: [
            { name: "bar", items: [2, 3] },
            { name: "baz", items: [3, 4] }
          ]
        }
      ];

      const projects = svg.selectAll('.project')
        .data(data)
        .join('g')
          .attr('class', 'project')
          .attr('data-project', d => d.project);

      const stages = projects.selectAll('.stage')
        .data(d => d.stages)
        .join('g')
          .attr('class', 'stage')
          .attr('data-stage', d => d.name);

      const range = stages.append('rect')
          .attr('class', 'range');

      const items = stages.selectAll('.item')
        .data(d => d.items)
        .join('rect')
          .attr('class', 'item')
          .attr('data-item', d => d);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The generated SVG:

```
<svg width="500" height="500">
  <g class="project" data-project="One">
    <g class="stage" data-stage="foo">
      <rect class="range"></rect>
      <rect class="item" data-item="1"></rect>
      <rect class="item" data-item="2"></rect>
      <rect class="item" data-item="3"></rect>
    </g>
    <g class="stage" data-stage="bar">
      <rect class="range"></rect>
      <rect class="item" data-item="2"></rect>
      <rect class="item" data-item="3"></rect>
    </g>
  </g>
  <g class="project" data-project="Two">
    <g class="stage" data-stage="bar">
      <rect class="range"></rect>
      <rect class="item" data-item="2"></rect>
      <rect class="item" data-item="3"></rect>
    </g>
    <g class="stage" data-stage="baz">
      <rect class="range"></rect>
      <rect class="item" data-item="3"></rect>
      <rect class="item" data-item="4"></rect>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```